# Both http and https for one service

Tags: wcf

I'm tackling with an issue but couldn't sort out it.

I have one service which is worked inside asp.net 4.0 app.
The site is available both over http and https.
Issue is that the service with below provided config snipped can work either over http or over https.

What is wrong in my config?

```
<system.serviceModel>
        <bindings>
            <webHttpBinding>
                <binding name="webHttpsBinding">
                    <security mode="Transport">
                        <transport clientCredentialType="None"/>
                    </security>
                </binding>
            </webHttpBinding>
        </bindings>
        <behaviors>
            <endpointBehaviors>
                <behavior name="HMS.DataServices.PaymentsServiceBehavior">
                    <enableWebScript />
                </behavior>
            </endpointBehaviors>
            <serviceBehaviors>
                <behavior name="HMS.DataServices.PaymentsServiceBehavior">
                    <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
                    <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false" />
                </behavior>
            </serviceBehaviors>
        </behaviors>
        <services>
            <service name="HMS.DataServices.PaymentsService">

                <!--HTTP-->
                <endpoint address="" binding="webHttpBinding" contract="HMS.DataServices.IPaymentsService" 
                          behaviorConfiguration="HMS.DataServices.PaymentsServiceBehavior" />

                <!--HTTPS-->
                <endpoint address="" binding="webHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="webHttpsBinding" 
                          contract="HMS.DataServices.IPaymentsService"  behaviorConfiguration="HMS.DataServices.PaymentsServiceBehavior" />
            </service>
        </services>
        <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
    </system.serviceModel>
```

this config works over https but not nttp

In the windows log I see next error

```
 The exception message is: Could not find a base address that matches scheme https for the endpoint with binding WebHttpBinding. Registered base address schemes are [http]..
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you sure that HTTPS is configured in IIS and https binding is allowed for hosting site?